# utf8 string length

Tags: php, string, utf-8

`strlen()` function in php could not return correctly string lenght of utf8 chars,  for example `سلام` is 4 char but after using strlen thats return 8 chr

```
<?php
echo strlen('سلام');
?>
```

Comment: byte size -> ```strlen()``` ex: ```strlen('a₹')``` -> ```4```. character count -> ```mb_strlen()``` ex: ```mb_strlen('a₹', "UTF-8")``` -> ```2```. Note: ```mb_strlen()``` is disabled by default in php.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The core PHP string functions all assume 1 character = 1 byte. They have no concept of different encodings. To figure out how many *characters* are in a UTF-8 string (not how many *bytes*), use the [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) equivalent and tell it what encoding the string is in:

```
echo mb_strlen('سلام', 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the number of UTF-8 Codepoints inside a binary PHP string (as long as it is valid UTF-8 encoded) ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eFBjoA)):

```
$length = preg_match_all('(.)su', $subject);
```

You can also use the multibyte extension if you have it installed:

```
$length = mb_strlen($subject, 'UTF-8');
```

See also: [PHP UTF-8 String Length](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/php-utf-8-string-length/)

Comment: Is there realistically a system where mb* is not available? I have yet to see one, to be honest. :)

Comment: To be honest, I've seen some. But this should not cause any difficulties in this case.

Comment: Be careful. In Unicode, *and therefore its encodings like UTF8*, a character can be composed by one or more codepoints. In fact, in many cases two apparently visualized similar characters might be composed by different number of codepoints.