# count string length received in UTF-16BE encoding using php

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8

A php script is receiving a string in UTF-16BE encoding in a HTTP GET parameter. I just want to count the characters of the string

to do this i convert it to utf-8

$str=iconv('utf-16be', 'utf-8', $str);

when i use strlen($str), it return wrong count. I can count it using

```
1) mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');

2) strlen(utf8_decode($str));
```

I want to know which one is the best way?
will both count all character correctly?

Comment: use only first variant, as utf8_decode will garble your text

Answer (score 1):

You have to look what these functions do actually.

- [**`strlen()`**](http://php.net/strlen) counts the binary length of a string - that is the number of bytes (or characters where one character is one byte).

This function is *not* suitable to count the number of Unicode code points in a UTF-16BE encoded binary string.

Instead you can use the

- [**`mb_strlen($string, "UTF-16BE")`**](http://php.net/mb_strlen) method (with the second parameter set to "`UTF-16BE`")

it should return the number of unicode code-points.

So what is the best way? This depends on what you want to find out.

If you need to get the binary length of a string, take `strlen`.

If you need to the the number of characters of a string with a specfic encoding, take `mb_strlen` with the correct encoding parameter.

That's all for the string length already.

---

For the other functions you name:

- [**`iconv()`**](http://php.net/iconv) recodes a string between different encodings. This is not always possible.
- [**`utf8_decode()`**](http://php.net/utf8_decode) recodes a string from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) which is not fitting for UTF-16BE at all.

these two are unrelated to string-length. Especially the combination you suggest:

```
$str = iconv('utf-16be', 'utf-8', $str);
$len = strlen(utf8_decode($str));
```

is not stable. Not stable means, it doesn't work for all UTF-16BE input. You can however recode from UTF-16BE to UTF-8 (here with `iconv`) and the get the UTF-8 string lengths (but not via `utf8_decode`):

- [utf8 string length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13508752/367456)